# Stressed plant - how long before pruning?

Tags: nightshade

I purchased (literally) distressed inventory from a local garden centre - Asian Eggplants which need A LOT of TLC, including water, larger pots, removal of way to much (mainly over ripe) fruit and heavy pruning.

I took them home, transplanted and watered them yesterday evening, but I also want to remove the fruit. How long do I need to give the plants to acclimatise to their new home before I can start fixing them?

Comment: add a picture please

Answer (score 3):

I would remove everything that is clearly superfluous, like overripe fruit and damaged / sick / excessively long branches immediately.

Every plant needs a balance between root mass and top growth, and if you see already that the existing roots are disproportionate (which I guess is the reason for repotting them), some  pruning now can help, leaving the plant with less foliage that needs to be supplied with water and minerals via the roots. And as cruel as it sounds, I recommend removing fruit and flowers. Stressed plants often direct their energy into these, a bit like a “last ditch effort” before dying. I would not, however, do a severe pruning right now, that may be a bit too much injury and you need the leaves for photosynthesis. Wait until new growth shows that the plants are perking up, then gradually start “fixing”.

Not part of your question and it will depend on your location and planting plans, but you may want to be a bit careful with full sun for your freshly repotted weak plants, give them a bit to put out feeder roots in the new pot to ensure a good water supply. That’s doubly important if the plants were indoors at the store. Plants get sunburn, too.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a very strong idea what needs to be done (ive grown eggplants commercially)  - what im looking for is **how long before I can do it**.

Comment: Immediately? At least cut the fruit and whatever won’t be good for photosynthesis and just “draw energy” (sorry, can’t think of a better term right now). Didn’t I say that clearly enough? Let me check...

Comment: Oh, and I know that you are experienced with aubergines, but as all Q/As should also be helpful for future readers, I just added a few extra details.